# MySQL Column variable table

Tags: mysql

```
|-------------------------|
| column_table            |
|-------------------------|
| column_id | column_name |
|-----------|-------------|
| 1         | column_1    |
|-----------|-------------|
| 2         | column_2    |
|-------------------------|



|-------------------|
| row_table         |
|-------------------|
| row_id | row_name |
|--------|----------|
| 1      | row_1    |
|--------|----------|
| 2      | row_2    |
|-------------------|



|--------------------------------------------|
| value_table                                |
|--------------------------------------------|
| value_id | column_id | row_id | value_name |
|----------|---------------------------------|
| 1        | 1         | 1      | value_11   |
|----------|---------------------------------|
| 2        | 2         | 1      | value_21   |
|--------------------------------------------|
| 3        | 1         | 2      | value_12   |
|--------------------------------------------|
| 4        | 2         | 2      | value_22   |
|--------------------------------------------|
```

Good day, tell me please, how I can design the Database to be able to add rows and columns to the resulting table? Either build a result table (apparently using a temporary table) as the table below.

```
|-----------------------------|
| result_table                |
|-----------------------------|
|       | column_1 | column_2 |
|-------|---------------------|
| row_1 | value_11 | value_21 |
|-------|---------------------|
| row_2 | value_12 | value_22 |
|-----------------------------|
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to accomplish.
Are you building a meta table structure, so you can allow users to design their own table structures in a web application?

If so, there are simpler ways to do it than the table structure you've outlined above.

Please give more details about your goal.

Comment: User should be able to add rows and columns to the table, that is, the table should be able to expand through rows and columns (vertically and horizontally)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have the following tables:

```
|-------------------------|
| column_table            |
|-------------------------|
| column_id | column_name |
|-----------|-------------|
| 1         | column_1    |
|-----------|-------------|
| 2         | column_2    |
|-------------------------|



|-------------------|
| row_table         |
|-------------------|
| row_id | row_name |
|--------|----------|
| 1      | row_1    |
|--------|----------|
| 2      | row_2    |
|-------------------|
```

You only then need a table like the following to store the value of each "virtual" table cell:

```
|-----------------------------------------|
| value_table                             |
|-----------------------------------------|
| value_id | row_id | column_id | value   |
|-----------------------------------------|
|     1    |    1   |     1     |  'Y'    |
|     2    |    1   |     2     |  915    |
|     3    |    2   |     1     |  'N'    |
|     4    |    2   |     1     |  883    |
|-----------------------------------------|
```

Then you can issue a query like the following to display results:

```
select   
        value_id
      , row_name
      , column_name
      , value
  from
      value_table v join

      column_table c on
             v.columnd_id = c.column_id      join

      row_table r on
             v.row_id = r.row_id

  where
      {{ some conditions }};
```

Comment: Yes, this is a good, working variant, the only one, in case each row contains several fields, and when it is necessary to save the previous rows values, if at least one cell is changed, it is necessary to duplicate the entire line, the information is redundant due to one cell